# Do health % runes stack with Vladimirs passive? If they do, how?

Tags: league-of-legends

There's a [rune that gives you 0.5% percent bonus health](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_runes#Percent_Health). [Vladimir's passive ability](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir#Crimson_Pact) reads as follows:

> Vladimir gains ability power equal to `2.5%` of his bonus health and bonus health equal to `140%` of his ability power. These bonuses do not stack with themselves.

My question is, how do these both stack together? Do you get greater health bonus for ability power? Or do you get more health *except* the passive which gives you more AP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes the percentage bonus health will give you bonus AP.**

If you have 1000 Bonus Health you'll get 25 bonus ability power from your passive. If you now have 2.5% bonus health (5 seals) also with 1000 bonus health, you'll have a total bonus health of 1025 resulting in an AP bonus of 26 AP (rounded up from 25.625).

Note that bonus health means health from Runes, Masteries and Items. Your base champion Health is ignored when it comes to these calculations meaning that flat Health marks are usually stronger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder - can I test it somehow? If possible, I test the answers before accepting but I actually asked this question because I have no idea how to find out...

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, its quite easy to test. Go into a custom game with a blank runepage, then hover over your passive.  Then go into another custom game with HP% runes and look at the passive again.  With that said, HP% runes aren't that good, as you need a lot of HP to make them better than regular HP/level or flat HP runes, but thats beside the point

Comment: My test has proven that base champion health **does** stack with % bonus health runes (tested on Dr. Mundo). With no masteries and no health runes, Mundo had 583 health at level 1. With 1% bonus health runes (2 seals) he had 589 (`583+5.83 = 588.83`). This makes me now unaccept the answer and investigate the thing further.